# How did Teddy get killed in the end again?

Tags: plot-explanation, memento

Does anybody remember the first scene when he killed teddy? How it happened while he met Teddy again and the film ended with Teddy is dead?

Answer (score 12):

Ok abdelaziz, I' not sure if you've grasped the concept of *Memento*...

As funny as your frantic panic is, I think I'd better explain....

The film is in **reverse order**, so the start is the end and vice-versa.

Each 'segment' begins just before the preceding one. So although we see Teddy die at the start, he is actually dying at the end of the films chronology.

[image]

Comment: Wow, great diagram (even if the specific bullet points are a bit hard to read, but that's SE's fault, I guess). I think to have heard that the DVD editions feature an entirely ascending chronological order for the whole movie (starting with the b/w phone calls and ending with *Teddy*'s death). While that somehow defeats a large part of *Memento*'s effect, it might still be an interesting view opening further insights.